# COUNT number of times prior to specified time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Hard to sum this up in a subject line. Basically what I need is a count of how many times a time exists prior to a specified time.

Example:

```
Column A  Column B
4:00 AM   7:00 AM
4:00 AM
4:00 AM
5:00 AM
6:00 AM
8:00 AM
```

So I need it to count how many times (Column A) have occurred prior to the time in column B. So in the above example, there were 5 cells in column A containing a time that was before the time in column B.

Hopefully that makes sense. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The 6 cells in column A that contained a time that was less than the time in column B.

Comment: only five cells, i think, there are five cells that are before the time in columb B, right?

Comment: Lol sorry guys, you are right. I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply try this one:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"<"&B1)
```

tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Aldentec then please accept it as the answer to your question by clicking the check mark below the vote count.

Comment: I still can't for 3 minutes. Don't worry I will!